# Jena adds path/url to URIs

Tags: rdf, jena

I just started working with RDF and Jena.
I got a RDF model which I want to read, modify and write out again.
Assume my model file is located at `http://xyz/model.ttl` and contains an element with URI "someURI". 
When I do

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
model.read("http://xyz/model.ttl", "", "TURTLE");
model.write(System.out, "TURTLE");
```

the URI in the output changes from "someURI" to `http://xyz/someURI`.
When I read the model from the local filesystem, the URI changes to `file://pathToFile/someURI`.
Is there a way to avoid this behaviour and keep the URI unchanged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RDF (like HTML) URLs (/ URIs / IRIs) are resolved relative to a base URL, typically the URL of the source document.

So reading `someURI` in `http://xyz/model.ttl` becomes `http://xyz/someURI`, and from a file you get `file://pathToFile/someURI`.

You can avoid this by supplying an explicit base, which will make the resulting URLs consistent across sources.

```
model.read("http://xyz/model.ttl", "http://xyz/model.ttl", "TURTLE");
// or with same result
model.read(fileSource, "http://xyz/model.ttl", "TURTLE");
```

and also relativise the result:

```
model.write(System.out, "TURTLE", "http://xyz/model.ttl");
```

(The documentation states that the base and lang arguments are switched for [reading](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [writing](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which seems odd)

Comment: About the ordering, and this is just a thought:  it's nice to provide the overloaded versions with fewer arguments, but with the arguments in the same order.  For reading, it's possible to guess the language, but not the base, so it makes sense for the language to be optional, and thus the final argument.  For writing, the base isn't needed very often (since all the IRIs should really be absolute anyhow), but the lang is more commonly specified (but it's optional too).  So it makes sense for the base to be the final argument for writing.

Comment: RDFdataMgr uses typed constants making the read/write operations not prone to string confusion.

Comment: 'Stringly typed' is an expression I'm rather fond of for this issue. RDFdataMgr is much better, of course. My IDE even lists the available options.

Comment: Adding to the answer, it can be a good practice to specify the base explicitly in the serialized document rather than at read time.

Comment: At first I thought the solution would work but now I have another problem.
I did everything exactly like posted above. 
When I run my jar from the terminal, my URIs now become `file://currentWorkingDirectory/someURI` instead of `file://pathToFile/someURI` or `http://xyz/someURI`