# Jena relative URI base

Tags: jena, relative-path

[Reading RDF in Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-input.html) states that,

> A resource name with no URI scheme is assumed to be a local file name.

This assumption can be overridden by providing a base URI to the various `read` methods of `RDFDataMgr`. But is there a way to treat relative URIs as errors, i.e. throw an exception if a relative URI is encountered in a given RDF document?

The question is similar to [Jena adds path/url to URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136333/jena-adds-path-url-to-uris) but in my case relative URIs represent an error condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of the answer by @RobV using `FactoryRDF`.

```java
static final String BASE = "null://null/";
static final FactoryRDF FACTORY = new FactoryRDFStd() {
    @Override
    public Node createURI(String uriStr) {
        if (uriStr.startsWith(BASE))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI is not absolute: " + uriStr.substring(BASE.length()));
        return super.createURI(uriStr);
    }
};

public static void main(String... args) {
    Model output = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    RDFParser.create()
             .fromString("<foo> <bar> <baz> .")
             .lang(Lang.TURTLE)
             .base(BASE)
             .factory(FACTORY)
             .parse(output.getGraph());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, it is possible to override the URI resolution behaviour. Thereby allowing you to substitute a resolver that refuses relative URIs. We use this in our production software which is built upon Apache Jena.

Our code does not apply to the code path you are interested in because we use this in SPARQL parsing which is a different API from parsing, and I can't share proprietary code anyway. However I think what you want to do is entirely achievable.

With recent versions of Jena there is a `RDFParserBuilder` class introduced which provides for constructing parsers with detailed control over parser behaviour. Converting terms in data into Jena `Node` objects is handled by the `FactoryRDF` Interface that can be set on the parser builder.  So you should be able to override that to implement your logic to reject relative URIs.

Comment: `FactoryRDF` is one way of doing it. Another way is to parse to `StreamRDF` and check the URIs in triples that go through.  `StreamRDF`s can be stacked.

Comment: From what I can see, `FactoryRDF` and `StreamRDF` only provide access to URIs _after_ conversion from relative to absolute form. This leaves the problem of determining whether an absolute URI _used to be_ relative. Is there an interface that taps into the relative URIs before they are converted to absolute form?

Comment: @AndyS, is there a way to do the same thing for writes? `RDFWriterBuilder` doesn't accept a Factory object to process the nodes.

Comment: FactoryRDF has nothing to do with writing. `RDFWriterBuilder` has a `base` method - is that what you are looking for? (RDF/XML may be different ; see https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-arq/src-examples/arq/examples/riot/ExRIOT_RDFXML_WriteProperties.java)

Comment: @AndyS, I'd like to create an `RDFWriter` that throws an exception if its source contains a relative URI.

Comment: Better to check the data before trying to write it.

Answer (score 0):

> A resource name with no URI scheme is assumed to be a local file name.

To expand on that documentation: This means

```
RDFDataMgr.read(Model, "mydata.ttl", ...)
```

will read file "mydata.ttl"

The base URI argument applies to the process parsing the data, not to choosing which data to read. Equivalently, the base URI for resource finding is the current working directory of the process.